AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'is_valid_reason' in GeoPandas
I was going over the documentation for checking on valid geometries. When I wanted to try the example for is_valid_reason, got this error:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

s = gpd.GeoSeries(
    [
        Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]),
        Polygon([(0,0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]),  # bowtie geometry
        Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 2), (2, 0)]),
        None
    ]
)
s.is_valid_reason()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13376\1248646713.py in ?()
      6         Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 2), (2, 0)]),
      7         None
      8     ]
      9 )
---> 10 s.is_valid_reason()

somepath\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\geo_mamba\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in ?(self, name)
   6295             and name not in self._accessors
   6296             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   6297         ):
   6298             return self[name]
-> 6299         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'is_valid_reason'

I'm using Python 3.12.2, shapely 2.0.4, and geopandas 0.14.4

Should add that as an answer.

Your code works fine on my Python 3.11 with GeoPandas 1.0.0 and shapely 2.0.4.
You will need to update your GeoPandas. Because you are using the 0.14.4 version.
The method is_valid_reason() was firstly added in GeoPandas 1.0.0, see the Changelog Version 1.0.0 (June 24, 2024) for more details.
